# how to get id value of the items by clicking

Tags: qt, qt4, qwt

Here is my problem and I totally want an advice, it will be helpful to me.

I want to add two items in my plot (for example two svg items). The first item is ID1, and the second item is ID2.

When I click the first svg item it should emit a signal. Similarly, when I click the second svg item it should emit another signal. But I dont want to use coordinates of items.

My aim is this, items must say to me their IDs when I click on them. **But I don't want to use coordinates of items. I can not figure it out how, please give me an advise.

Regards.

Comment: How do you represent your svg objects? How are the signals connected ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to do this without dealing with coordinates, since `QwtPlotItem` processes only paint events. Qwt doesn't route mouse events to items, so you need to implement this behavior manually.

- Install an event filter on plot's `canvas()` and intercept mouse events.
- Use `QwtPlot::invTransform` to convert mouse coordinates to values corresponding to x and y axes.
- Iterate over `QwtPlot::itemList` and check if each item's `QwtPlotItem::boundingRect` contains clicked point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I am using the method which is same technique as your answer. I am drawing those items with respect to datas in xml files. I mean coordinates are changing randomly. So i think i should draw without coordinates. And my brain stops in this point.